# How can I make a path of Python2.7 to use PyPDF2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

how can I put the path of python to use the PyPDF2 .. and about the PyPDF2 did i need to download it and add it to python files ? I am a beginner in python and I need to learn about how to read the text form PDF file. help me :)

Comment: is pip installed on your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have pip. You should firstly install pip.

If you have pip then open your command line(cmd) and type below command it will install library to your computer.

```
pip install pypdf2
```

if successfull installed on your computer then you can import pypdf2 to use.

Comment: i don't think that i have the pip , how can i get it ?

Comment: Also there is a youtube video on installing pip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPMr0lEMqpo